# Unable to increment variable (object oriented programming)

Tags: java, oop, static, increment

I'm stuck on Task2 where i have to increment the counter of enemyships each time an enemy is created. I have created the enemey ships already and made the counter field static (i'm suppose to call the counter number)

The final solution should increment the counter of number enemyships which i need to declare a static field, the field should start at 0, when the first enemyship is created should increment this field to 1, second increment to 2 and so on, then you can use the value of this feild when printing the first line of output. that is for the first enemy, you should print "Enemy #1" second enemy should print "Enemy #2" and so on.

So this is what I tried from my Enemyship class:

```
public class EnemyShip
{
    private int position;
    private int velocity;
    private int life;
    private static int number = 0;
    private boolean justHit;

    public EnemyShip()
    {
        System.out.println("Enemy #1");
        System.out.print("- Initial position: ");
        position = Global.keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("- Initial velocity: ");
        velocity = Global.keyboard.nextInt();
    }

}
```

i made the public void increment method and tried to use this to increment but it didn't work. wondering if someone could help me explain how i can fix this problem and how to increment a variable in java.
thanks

```
public class Game { 
    private PlayerShip player;
    private EnemyShip enemy1; 
    private EnemyShip enemy2; 
    private EnemyShip enemy3; 
    public Game() { 
        player = new PlayerShip(); 
        enemy1 = new EnemyShip(); 
        enemy2 = new EnemyShip(); 
        enemy3 = new EnemyShip(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You keep saying it doesn't work. What doesn't? What's your expectation and the actual result?

Comment: Paste your `main()` method. Are you printing to a standard output? Like the windows console?

Comment: How are you running your application? Where is the output coming from? This is very unclear.

Comment: Ok, forget blueJ for a while, it's obviously not printing what we expect it to print and not because the code is wrong. Try to run the code from a `main()` method in an IDE or from the command line.

Comment: main() method how do I do that?

Comment: Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/

Comment: class EnemyShip {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enemy #1");
    }
} (like that?)

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) {new EnemyShip(); new EnemyShip(); new EnemyShip();}`. You need to read a few Java tutorials, I think.

Comment: You can put it there too. Why don't you just try it? There's no fun in just getting the answer.

Comment: See my newest edit. I think you are blocked somewhere in your understanding of Java. Please read the tutorials in the links I provided

Comment: Please don't edit my answer. Edit your question. Also, the output you are getting makes absolutely no sense and contains characters that aren't even printed in the code. Please use a better IDE or run the application on command line.

Comment: You can always change the output later. Just make sure you understand the concepts that are involved. We don't know the expected output, so it's up to you to make those changes.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an `increment()` method and why do you increment by 3 every time?

The `number` variable is `static` so you have access to it anywhere inside your class.

Use it and increment it in the Constructor.

```
public EnemyShip()
{
    System.out.print("- Initial position: ");
    position = Global.keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("- Initial velocity: ");
    velocity = Global.keyboard.nextInt();
    life = 10;
    boolean justHit = false;
    number++;
    System.out.println("Enemy #" + number);
}
```

Every time you call

```
new EnemyShip();
```

you will see the statement

```
Enemy #[some number]
```

If you want to remember which `EnemyShip` has which number, you can add an instance field.

```
private int shipNumber;

public EnemyShip()
{
    System.out.print("- Initial position: ");
    position = Global.keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("- Initial velocity: ");
    velocity = Global.keyboard.nextInt();
    life = 10;
    boolean justHit = false;
    shipNumber = ++number;
    System.out.println("Enemy #" + shipNumber);
}
```

This solution is dangerous in a multithreaded environment. I still don't know what your `increment()` method is for.

**EDIT**

You seem to be all over the place, lacking some bacis java knowledge of how classes work. 
Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/) and all of [these](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Then run this code

```
public class EnemyShip {
    private static int number = 0;

    public EnemyShip() {
        number++;
        System.out.println("Enemy #" + number);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new EnemyShip();
        new EnemyShip();
        new EnemyShip();
    }
}
```

It will output

```
Enemy #1
Enemy #2
Enemy #3
```

Comment: I was using the increment method to increment

Comment: @user2736476 Yes, but it was incrementing the counter by 3 every time. That didn't necessarily follow any logic that I could find in your problem.

Comment: @user2736476 Every time you call `increment`, the `number` variable value would jump by 3. You said you wanted it to jump by 1. The right way to do this is in the controller, so that you aren't affected if you forget to call `increment()`.

Comment: @user2736476 The `Enemy #1` you see is because of the `System.out.println()` you used to have at the beginning of your constructor. Get rid of it. See my edit.

Comment: @user2736476 I don't know how you're running this code. Each new EnemyShip you create will have a +1 `#`.

Comment: @user2736476 Please edit your question and add the code with which your initializing `EnemyShip`. What you're saying makes no sense without context.

Comment: @user2736476 The code I've posted will post a different number for each `EnemyShip`. I've tried it with what you've shown. Is your output being trimmed?

Comment: @user2736476 What is `<`??? Are you doing something to standard output? Are you printing to console?

Comment: @user2736476 You must be doing something to `System.out`. What you're explaining doesn't just happen. My output, excluding initial velocity and position, is `Enemy #1`, new line, `Enemy #2`, new line, `Enemy #3`

Comment: @user You can edit your original question. There's a link at the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have provided, I understand you have to increment the value of `counter` everytime an enemy ship is created. So every time you call the constructor you should increment counter.So your `increment` function should look like this:

```
public void increment()
{
number = number + 1;
System.out.println("Enemy " + number + "#");
}
```

Comment: You said you want to increment count everytime a new enemyship gets created and that is what the code above does. when the first enemyship is created it should print Enemy #1 why Enemy #2??? Please edit your question to clearly explain your problem, the expected input and output.

Comment: remember that you have to call increment explicitly everytime you create a new enenmyship. change your Game class:public class Game { 
    private PlayerShip player;
    private EnemyShip enemy1; 
    private EnemyShip enemy2; 
    private EnemyShip enemy3; 
    public Game() { 
        player = new PlayerShip(); 
        enemy1 = new EnemyShip();enemy1.increment(); 
        enemy2 = new EnemyShip(); enemy2.increment();
        enemy3 = new EnemyShip(); enemy3.increment();
    } 
}

Comment: can you explain clearly what you meant, because i couldn't follow your above comment... and did you add enemy2.increment(); after enemy2=new EnemyShip()???

Comment: no, according to the question you should be getting Enemy #1 after the first enemyship is created, why should you expect Enemy #2 after the first one is created. You should expect Enemy #2 after the second enemyship is created which is exactly what the code does.So why the confusion???

Answer (score 0):

OP, you need to call the increment method from somewhere. The method won't run unless you call the method.

```
public class Game { 
    private PlayerShip player;
    private EnemyShip enemy1; 
    private EnemyShip enemy2; 
    private EnemyShip enemy3; 
    public Game() { 
        player = new PlayerShip(); 
        enemy1 = new EnemyShip();  EnemyShip.increment();
        enemy2 = new EnemyShip();  EnemyShip.increment(); 
        enemy3 = new EnemyShip();   EnemyShip.increment();
    } 
}
```

Should do better for you.